# Has anyone been able to get recurring payments working with Google Checkout?

Tags: google-checkout, recurring

I'm working with a non-profit who has been given a grant by Google that removed the 2.9% fee that Google Checkout applies to each charge that uses the service.

Because of this we are looking to it as a primary candidate for an upgrade of our donations system, the chief new feature of which is to allow for recurring donations.

I've been reading all the documentation I can find on the topic, but have found precious little about how to work with recurring payments.

Before I spend too much more time on it, I'm wondering if anyone can offer their experience with it.

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

There is a beta service (Google Checkout Subscriptions) that handles recurring payments:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Beta_Subscriptions.html

For additional info and questions/feedback from developers implementing the Checkout Subscriptions see the "Checkout Betas" developer forum:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/checkout-merchants/label?lid=4d0694a52e181606&hl=en

Comment: Do you have any experience with it?